# How to hide or make edges invisible for some time & restore them again using graphviz or networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz

I tried giving it color white but it is giving back a thick white line.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post your code

Answer (score 0):

use color=transparent instead of white to hide an edge